# How do I reference an assembly from a custom scaffolder in visual studio 2013 rc2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, t4, scaffolding

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.dll in my t4 template. I have an assembly directive that looks like this

```
<#@ assembly name="..\..\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" #>
```

This worked well in the pre 2013 scaffolding world, but now it doesn't find this assembly. What is the proper way to reference an external assembly that is already in the packages folder?

Here is the location of the assembly.

{solutiondir}\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [SolutionDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586946.aspx)?

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.5.0.6\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" #>
```

Make sure to match the Newtonsoft.Json version with what you are using.

Comment: This works when I use a t4 template and run the custom tool. It would also work when MS Build runs. It doesn't work with MVCScaffolding.